# How to strip EXIF info from files in OSX with batch or command line

Tags: macos, images, exif

I know there are several Windows programs to do this, and Photoshop has a "Save for Web" option which does this, but I want a command line or batch processing option for this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried Automator, maybe with third party actions (e.g. Pixelmator?)?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have a look at [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). Its `-strip` option clear an image of any profiles and comments.

```
convert orig.jpg -strip result.jpg
```

or

```
mogrify -strip orig.jpg
```

Here's [more info](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/) on photo handling with Imagemagick.

Comment: I did not want to spend a lot of time and although was interested to work with Imagemagick, spend 10+ minutes configuring it. I tried SmallImage and got what I wanted in 2 min.

Comment: @user200507 To quote the OP, "I want a command line option, or a batch processing option for this." I stand by Imagemagick as being the best at this.

Comment: Imagemagick's `strip` also stripped the green and blue channels from my semi-transparent red circle, leaving a no-metadata opaque red circle.

Comment: WARNING! `mogrify` did *not* remove the `kMDItemWhereFroms                  = (` metadata for me! (`convert` did, though). It was extremely damning metadata too, because it included my full name and even that I had airdropped the photo from my iPhone. You can view this metadata with `mdls`.

Answer (score 14):

I use macOS — currently 11.1 (Big Sur) — and I like to use [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/) for batch metadata operations like this. Have used it from Mac OS X 10.6 onwards and even on different flavors of Linux such as Ubuntu and it works great.

As far as bulk scripting goes, I use this very simply Bash script that uses [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to wipe all metadata from images; in this case JPEG (`.jpg`) images:

```
find 'Path/To/The/Images' -type f -name '*.jpg' |\
  while read FILENAME
  do
    exiftool -all= -overwrite_original_in_place "${FILENAME}"
  done
```

To use the script just change the `'Path/To/The/Images'` to match your actual image file directory path; it can be a full path or relative and in this case it is relative. And you can change `'*.jpg'` to match whatever file extension you wish to act on or even set it to `'*'` to blindly process all files. I usually deal with JPEGs thus the `.jpg` extension in this small example script.

And the core magic to that script is the actual `exiftool` command which can be further simplified to this:

```
exiftool -all= -overwrite_original_in_place image_filename.jpg
```

The `-all=` is what wipes the metadata by setting all metadata fields to the value that equals nothing. The `-overwrite_original_in_place` will overwrite the actual image. It does not reprocess the image past reading the file, acting on the metadata and writing it back to the system. Without that flag `exiftool` will copy the original file with an extension that has `_original` appended to it; so in this case it would be `image_filename.jpg_original`. And the final parameter is simply the filename you want to act on.

Comment: `exiftool -all=` will remove the ICC color profile, which is now more of a problem than it used to be because some iPhones use a P3 profile while the default (for images without a profile) remains sRGB. I recommend `exiftool -exif:all= -iptc:all= -time:all=` instead.

Comment: @OldPro Good info! Post it as a fuller answer and I will gladly upvote that!

Answer (score 5):

The [exiv2](http://exiv2.org/) tool (installable using homebrew) provides a quick and simple way to remove the EXIF information from one or more files e.g.:

```
exiv2 rm myfile1.jpg myfile1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

actually nconvert strips far more from the jpgs

http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert/#downloads

```
nconvert.exe -rmeta -rexifthumb -o small.jpg big.jpg
```